# How do I import the data on this Website using Importxml on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently trying to import via importxml on GoogleSheets the entire Table on a website but it dosen't return the data. The formula I'm using is =IMPORTXML("https://dinem.magyp.gob.ar/dinem_fob.wp_fob_conslista.aspx?20230922,1338,178,1";"//*"). What is wrong there?

I tried the following formula =IMPORTXML("https://dinem.magyp.gob.ar/dinem_fob.wp_fob_conslista.aspx?20230922,1338,178,1";"//*") but it allways returns only the headers.

Comment: I would use a Chrome Snippet written in Javascript.  It's very easy because the DOM is live

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the HTML of your URL, it seemed that the table was created by Javascript. In this case, unfortunately, the table cannot be directly retrieved using IMPORTXML. But, fortunately, it seems that the values of the table are included in the HTML as JSON data. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, save the script.

When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE()` into a cell. By this, the script is run.

```js
function SAMPLE() {
  const url = "https://dinem.magyp.gob.ar/dinem_fob.wp_fob_conslista.aspx?20230922,1338,178,1";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const match = res.getContentText().match(/<input.*name\="GridContainerDataV".*value='(.*?)'.*?>/);
  if (!match) return "No values";
  const header = ["Producto", "Descripción", "Precio (Dls/Ton)", "Emb.Desde", "Emb.Hasta"];
  const obj = JSON.parse(match[1]);
  return [header, ...obj.map(([a, ...v]) => {
    const temp = [...a];
    temp.splice(6, 0, "-");
    temp.splice(4, 0, "-");
    return [temp.join(""), ...v.map(e => e == 0 ? null : e)];
  })];
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. It seems that this result is the same as the table in the HTML.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used to the current HTML of your URL. When the structure of the HTML is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- When you want to put the values without using the custom function, you can also use the following script.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const url = "https://dinem.magyp.gob.ar/dinem_fob.wp_fob_conslista.aspx?20230922,1338,178,1";
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    const match = res.getContentText().match(/<input.*name\="GridContainerDataV".*value='(.*?)'.*?>/);
    if (!match) return "No values";
    const header = ["Producto", "Descripción", "Precio (Dls/Ton)", "Emb.Desde", "Emb.Hasta"];
    const obj = JSON.parse(match[1]);
    const values = [header, ...obj.map(([a, ...v]) => {
      const temp = [...a];
      temp.splice(6, 0, "-");
      temp.splice(4, 0, "-");
      return [temp.join(""), ...v.map(e => e == 0 ? null : e)];
    })];

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)